# SQL PIVOT - MS SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server

Alright, I'm sure this answer exists out there, but I honestly don't know enough to phrase the question properly to find the answer by searching (I've definitely tried).

I'm trying to join multiple tables, and add columns where data is different (instead of adding a row of identical data except for the one column that is different).

As an example, let's say I have the following 2 tables.

Table name: COUNTRY

```
| Country ID |  Name  | Location | Climate |
+------------+--------+----------+---------+
|          1 | Canada | North    | Cold    |
|          2 | USA    | South    | Warm    |
|          3 | Russia | North    | Cool    |
+------------+--------+----------+---------+
```

Table Name: POPULATION

```
| Country ID | Year | Population |
+------------+------+------------+
|          1 | 1990 |         10 |
|          1 | 1995 |         15 |
|          1 | 2000 |         18 |
|          2 | 1990 |         12 |
|          2 | 1995 |         22 |
|          2 | 2000 |         25 |
|          3 | 1990 |          3 |
|          3 | 1995 |          5 |
|          3 | 2000 |          7 |
+------------+------+------------+
```

When I do a join with these, I would get three rows of "Canada" with the population values for each of the three years.

What I want though, is this:

```
|  Name   | Climate | Pop 1990 | Pop 1995 | Pop 2000 |
+---------+---------+----------+----------+----------+
| Canada  | Cold    |       10 |       15 |       18 |
| USA     | Warm    |       12 |       22 |       25 |
| Russian | Cool    |        3 |        5 |        7 |
+---------+---------+----------+----------+----------+
```

Comment: Please edit your title to improve it.  It should briefly summarize your question.  The fact that you are a "Newb" is irrelevant and doesn't belong in the title.

Comment: This is commonly referred to as a PIVOT. Please update the tags on this question with the RDBMS you are using as the implementation of PIVOT is different across databases (Oracle vs SQL Server vs MySql vs Postgres etc.)

Comment: Thanks for both of the above suggestions.  Just knowing that this is a pivot may be answer enough for my question!  Sometimes a guy doesn't know enough to even know what to search for.

Comment: If the number of years is fixed "1990, 1995, 2000" then you can do a pivot. If the number of years can vary then you need to look at how to do a dynamic pivot.

Comment: Yes, when translated over to the actual database I'm using, the 'year identifier' in this example would be fixed.  (it's a 4 digit cost code, where I'd be able to say something like "if cost_code=1234", so "if year=1990" is the same)

Answer (score 1):

should be something like this:

```
select name,climate,[1990] 'Pop 1990',[1995] 'Pop 1995',[2000] 'Pop 2000'
from (
select 
c.name
,c.climate
,p.[year]
,p.[Population]
from [POPULATION] p 
join COUNTRY c
on p.[Country ID] = c.[Country ID]) t
pivot
( sum([Population])
for [year] in ([1990],[1995],[2000])
)pvt
```

Comment: You may have to do the join in a CTE or subquery.  The extra `[Country ID]` may cause this to expand as written.

Comment: the join is in subquery

Comment: Lol... That's what I get for expecting clean formatting :)